# Linq Query to compare if collection contains list of string

Tags: vb.net, linq, list, collections

Im fairly new to Linq and am trying to write a search results query.

We use a tagging system for our help desk and Im trying to return all cases that contain tags or children of TAGS selected from a drop down list.

I am using a path comparison to find any children tags which works well when there is only 1 tag selected. This is my code for when multiples tags are selected but it is not working. Can you point me in the right direction?

Single Tag Selection (working)

```
   Dim tagpath = uxTags.SelectedItem.Text
   lnqCases = From i In lnqCases Where i.HelpDeskTagItems.Any(Function(x) x.Path.StartsWith(tagpath))
```

Multi Tag Selection (not working)

```
    Dim tagpaths As New List(Of String)
    For Each i In TagList.SelectedItems
      tagpaths.Add(i.ToString)
    Next
    lnqCases = From i In lnqCases Where i.HelpDeskTagItems.Any(Function(x) x.Path.StartsWith(tagpaths.Any))
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the logic, check for the Path within the list

```
lnqCases = From i In lnqCases Where i.HelpDeskTagItems.Any(Function(x) tagpaths.Contains(x.Path))
```

Or to continue the StartsWith logic

```
lnqCases = From i In lnqCases Where i.HelpDeskTagItems.Any(Function(x) Test.Exists(Function(m) m.StartsWithPath(x)))
```